# positioning the box down

Tags: html, css

Im trying to move the positioning of box8 more down but for some reason it's not moving. Instead its moving down container 4.. please help![image: Trying to move the white box down not the image]

Im trying to move the positioning of box8 more down but for some reason it's not moving. Instead its moving down container 4.. please help

HTML

```
<div id="con4">

<div id="box8">
<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="from"> 
<br>
Last name: <br>
<input type="text" placeholder="to">

<input type="date" value="date" placeholder="depart date">
<br>
<input type="date" value="date" placeholder="return date">

<input type="text" placeholder="airline"> 

or fly one way

</form>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
     #con4 {
     width:1024px;
     height:470px;
     background-image: url(media/plane.jpg);
     float:none;

      }

    #box8 {
    width:300px;
    height:340px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:50px;


    }
```

Comment: Need to move the white box down not the image

Comment: What is with people and their obsession with using IDs?? Use classes people!

Comment: @SeanStopnik Can you explain why the OP should use classes instead of IDs in this example? It's clear that there is only one form on the page, so it's not like you have multiple elements you need to style the same way. (Note that in this case, the ID names do sound more like they should be class names, but that's beside the point.)

Comment: @MrLister can you me one good reason to use IDs?

Comment: @SeanStopnik Hey, that is not nearly the same question as "why are people obsessed with using IDs". But OK, one good reason: as a fragment identifier. Suppose there is more content on this page, and you want to be able to show this part at the top of the window, then you can write `http://websiteurl#con4`

Comment: @MrLister well then you can add an ID for an anchor, but you shouldnt use the ID for a CSS hook. Leave IDs for anchors or possibly JS hooks, but don't use them for CSS hooks. Just bad practice with zero benefits.

Comment: @SeanStopnik There is no way you can conclude from this small snippet that IDs are used solely for CSS. I mean, this is not even the real HTML used on the OP's website!

Comment: @MrLister I don't need to conclude anything. I'm saying don't use IDs. Obviously they are attaching CSS to it... There are no classes. Don't agree with me... Fine. But I'd suggest researching it a bit.

Comment: I use id's because i feel like it easier lol, if i felt confident about using classes i would probably use them! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(sigh) The infamous collapsing margins problem again. I see a lot of those lately.
The margin you give to box8 is shared by con4, so they both move down the same amount.

Solution: don't give a margin-top to box8, give a padding-top to con4 instead.

```css
#con4 {
  width: 1024px;
  height: 470px;
  background-image: url(//lorempixel.com/1024/470);
  float: none;
  padding-top:50px;
}
#box8 {
  width: 300px;
  height: 340px;
  margin-left: 120px;
  background-color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="con4">

  <div id="box8">
    <form>
      First name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="from">
      <br>Last name:
      <br>
      <input type="text" placeholder="to">

      <input type="date" value="date" placeholder="depart date">
      <br>
      <input type="date" value="date" placeholder="return date">

      <input type="text" placeholder="airline">or fly one way

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

(Note that I had to change the background-image for con4 to make it visible)

Answer (score 0):

Add padding to the `con4` instead of margin to `box8`

```
   #con4 {
     width:1024px;
     height:470px;
     background: #000;
     float:none;
     padding-top:100px;
      }

    #box8 {
    width:300px;
    height:340px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    position:relative;
      }
```

http://jsbin.com/mejatayaqu/2/

Answer (score 0):

@lily replace your css with this:

```
#con4 {
     width:1024px;
     height:470px;
     background-image: url(media/plane.jpg);
     float:none;
      }

#box8 {
    width:300px;
    height:340px;
    margin-left: 120px;
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:50px;
    }
```